# Is there a way to ignore the AND in a CASE when something is true?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have this `Where` clause

```
Select * From Student_Info si
Inner Join Certifications cc
Inner Join Cert_Earned ce

Where si.grad_date = @grad_date
AND cc.org_no = @org_no
```

but I need an additional `AND` that should be ignored if it turns out the value is false, I will want *ALL* certificates

```
AND cc.industrial = CASE WHEN @industrial = 0 THEN Do Nothing
                     Else @industrial
```

Comment: Don't use case expressions in the where clause, stick to AND/OR instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would normally be expressed as:

```
AND (@industrial = 0 OR ccc.industrial = @industrial)
```

Comment: I think we're getting tripped up here, I want all values, if `@industrial` is `0`

Comment: @christopherclark That's exactly what the clause would do.  If it's `0`, it would evaluate as `true`.  If it's not `0`, it evaluates whether `ccc.industrial` equals the value, and only then would it be `true`.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a tough thought process to get around. Thanks that did work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to add a predicate that does an OR between two different conditions

```
AND (@industrial = 0 or ccc.industrial = @industrial)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with CASE functions:

```
AND 1 = (CASE WHEN @industrial = 0 THEN 1 
              ELSE CASE WHEN cc.industrial = @industrial THEN 1 END
         END)
```

or if cc.industrial is not nullable, then maybe:

```
AND cc.industrial = CASE WHEN @industrial = 0 THEN cc.industrial
                     Else @industrial END
```